# Android third party causes "app not installed" error

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, apk, failed-installation

I have created with the use of android studio a small project and then I generated the signed apk. Then I tried to install it in three phones and in the first one (which has android 8) the app was installed successfully but in the second one (which has android 4.2) and third one (which has android 5) I got the "app not installed" error. This is my second app (project) and my first one has been installed successfully in all these three phones. The minimum SDK version of the app is Android 4.0.3 (API level 15), so that's not causing the problem. Can anyone guess where the problem is?

Comment: Play protect option added in playstore app can you please check it . turned it off and then try to install your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign the apk with both v1 and v2 signatures. this is the most likely culprit given your scenario. apk will not get installed on devices with less than marshmallow if you only sign with v2

Comment: That was causing the problem. I signed the app with both signatures and it now works on all phones. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try following:

1. Change install location of app on the phones it's creating problem.
2. Try resetting app preferences
3. Clear Data and Cache of Package Installer
4. Allow Apps from Unknown Sources (Go to **Settings** → **Security** → **Unknown Sources**. Enable Unknown Sources. And then try installing App)
5. Try Deleting `.android_secure/smdl2tmpl.asec` file from your SD Card if using SD card
6. Resign the app.
7. Try changing app codes by using some apk editor app